My computer keeps coming out of sleep even though I've turned off all the wake sources
I've got a newish computer, and the biggest problem I have is that the thing will not stay asleep.
As soon as I tell it to sleep (or when the sleep timer fires), the display turns off, and the computer goes to sleep for about 5-30 seconds, then wakes up again.
powercfg -lastwake says that the wake source is coming from the USB controller, but there aren't any wake sources enabled:
PS C:\Users\eric> powercfg -lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Device
    Instance Path: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_7A60&SUBSYS_7E061462&REV_11\3&11583659&0&A0
    Friendly Name: Intel(R) USB 3.20 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.20 (Microsoft)
    Description: USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller
    Manufacturer: Generic USB xHCI Host Controller


PS C:\Users\eric> powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
NONE


PS C:\Users\eric> powercfg -devicequery wake_programmable
HID-compliant system controller (001)
Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (3) I225-V
APC UPS
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (001)
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (002)
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (003)
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (004)
WDF KinectSensor Interface 0
Realtek USB 2.5GbE Family Controller
HID-compliant mouse (001)
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device (001)
TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF2 advanced mode)
HID-compliant system controller (003)
HID-compliant consumer control device
HID-compliant mouse (002)
HID-compliant consumer control device (001)
Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz

Is there any way to figure out what's actually waking my computer up?
More importantly, how do I get that device to stop waking the computer up?

I would suspect Kinnect ... it could be detecting motion

As a test. Disconnect each device one by one eliminating each device as a candidate

Actually, that's not what I really want - what I want is for the offending device to stop waking the computer.

I have not vetted this for accuracy, but from reddit: "MS changed from legacy S3 sleep state to S0  sleep state on Windows 11. [...] The command "powercfg /DEVICEQUERY wake_armed" returned "NONE", but in effect ALL devices were set to wake up the laptop from sleep. [resolved by setting sleep state to "Linux S3" in BIOS]".

@Yorik I went into the BIOS and didn't find anything like "Sleep state", but I did find some settings about waking on LAN; turning those off seems to have reduced the wakeups, but I do still get a few.
